# Problem with big numbers in C

Tags: c, int

why should a code like this should provide a so high result when I give it the number 4293974227 (or higher)

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{


unsigned long long int i;

unsigned long long int z = atoi(argv[1]);

unsigned long long int tmp1 = z;


unsigned long long int *numbers = malloc (sizeof (unsigned long long int) * 1000);

for (i=0; tmp1<=tmp1+1000; i++, tmp1++) {

    numbers[i] = tmp1;
    printf("\n%llu - %llu", numbers[i], tmp1);
}

}
```

Result should start with the provided number but starts like this:

```
18446744073708558547 - 18446744073708558547
18446744073708558548 - 18446744073708558548
18446744073708558549 - 18446744073708558549
18446744073708558550 - 18446744073708558550
18446744073708558551 - 18446744073708558551
```

ecc...

What's this crap??

Thanks!

Comment: `atoi` (and friends) cannot detect errors. `atoi("foobar")` invokes undefined behaviour (possibly returns `0`) and gives no indication of an error. Stick with `strtol` (and friends)

Comment: Don't be so quick to label something as "crap" when you don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`atoi()` returns `int`.  If you need larger numbers, try [`strtol()`, `strtoll()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html), or their relatives.

Comment: strtoll doesn't just require argv[1] but other parameters which I don't understand. What's a "base"? I'm confused.

Comment: @Joseph, did you read the man page?  The "base" is in the mathematical sense.  You probably want to pass either `10` or `0` for your particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

`atoi()` returns `(int)`, and can't deal with `(long long)`.  Try `atoll()`, or failing that `atol()` (the former is preferred).

Comment: `atoll()` is not standard; `strtoll()` is.

Comment: @Nemo: "The `atoll()` function conforms to ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (``ISO C99'')." according to references I see. That said, `strtoll()` is probably better anyway.

Comment: My mistake; both are standard.  Apologies (and +1)

Comment: Although [the spec for atoll](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atol.html) does seem to point you toward strtoll().  (See the "Application Usage" section.)

Comment: @Nemo: that's why I said "probably better", but I matched the original idiom. I usually avoid the `ato*()` family, although not to the same extent as `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing signed integers as unsigned.